# Top tag reputation height is too small

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

On the `REPUTATION` block, the reputation indicator height of "Top tag" is too small, compared to the tag itself:

[image: Top tag reputation bug]

The reason is that the `.-rep-increase` class is on the wrong element, when I moved it to its parent element the reputation was the same height as the tag (23.59px):

[image: Tog tag reputation fix]

Hope I made it more clear with the above screenshots.

Tested on Chrome Version 59.0.3071.109 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows 10

Comment: Good find. I'll fix this soon.

Comment: +0.5 for the green hand drawn circle, would be x2 if it would be another shade of red.

Comment: @kayess Yes, but what about the blue arrow?